# entering data into array without entering key

Tags: java

I have said before, I'm really new to Java. I already use PHP as well. If I understand correct, we need to give java how long array will be.  Then what about automatic entering?

In php

```
<?php 

$data[] = 15;
$data[] = 18;
$data[] = 40;

print_r($data);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 18 [2] => 40 )
```

As you can see I didn't define array's length(this is not my question). Php can defining keys automaticly. I don't need to use like `$data[0] = 15; $data[1] = 18;`. In java how to do that? Need I use like below?

```
int dizi[] = new int[3];
dizi[0] = 15;
dizi[1] = 18;
dizi[2] = 40;
```

Is there any way?

Comment: You might want to consider a java list  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of an array is static. The lenght of collections like List, Map is not. Use List for example instead.

```
List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<>(); // Java 7 needed for diamond init
exampleList.add("test");
exampleList.add("test1");
exampleList.add("test2");
exampleList.add("test3");

for(str : exampleList){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

To initialize an array you allways need to know it's size in advance no matter if you do

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

or

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

NOTE: For previous versions of java you need to write `List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<String>();`. `List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();` will not compile in pre java 7 versions.

Comment: I added another initialization for older versions of java. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: I think I accidentaly resaved that. Feel free to add it again.

Comment: using "<>" is answer of my question?

Comment: Using an ArrayList is.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), for instance, an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

It does not have a predefined size and you can add as many element as you want. For instance:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a string");
list.add("another string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize array when you create it like this:

```
int[] dizi = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. You should use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. It provides comfortable modification operations and with the `toArray()` method you can always get a native array again if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write:

```
int[] anArray = { 
    100, 200, 300,
    400, 500, 600, 
    700, 800, 900, 1000
};
```

See here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

In java you have to use [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or Vector for growing arrays.

Then

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
```